# Write to two registers at the same time in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, copy-paste, vim-registers

I'm using:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

So that cut and copied selections go to the `*` register, which is conveniently linked to the `x` clipboard (I'm using Linux).

I would like to have it also in the `+` register  to get both middle-mouse-pasting and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> giving the same results in other applications. I guess this might related to the difference between `xclip` and `xclip -selection c`.

For now my workaround is:

```
noremap Y "+y
```

So that I could do `Yy` to copy the current line to `+` register and then use Ctlr-V in some applications. But then I have to think in advance if I will use the mouse or Ctrl-V.

Is there a way I could have the `+` and `*` registers have the same value when I yank or when I select some text with the mouse?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `noremap Y ygv"+y`, that would copy it to the `unnamed` clipboard and then save it to the `+` clipboard.

Comment: If that works out for you please say so, so that I can put it in an answer and you can accept it. :)

Comment: So, the funny thing, :map Y "+ygvy works but not the other way around.. do you think I could map that to y? How I can make that to work with the mouse selection as well (i.e. just selecting some text, no pressing anything, and then pasting with the two methods somewhere else?

Comment: That's certainly funny. lol. I'll put this in an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to

```
:set clipboard+=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

From the help:

> unnamedplus   A variant of "unnamed" flag which uses the clipboard
>                   register '+' (|quoteplus|) instead of register '*' for
>                   all operations except yank.  Yank shall copy the text
>                   into register '+' and also into '*' when "unnamed" is
>                   included.

Note that you need a fairly new Vim 7.3 (patchlevel 151?) for this option value.

Comment: Wow! Nice one Ingo! @elmanuelito would probably go for this one if it works. :)

Comment: @ingo karkat, I'm sorry, it does not seem to work for me, I probably do it wrong. I do a simple yy or dd or x, then :reg and "+ and "* are different. My .vimrc is empty except for your command.  --- My vim version: Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov 22 2012 15:42:28) Included patches: 1-547   --- 
And here's my clipboard variable: clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux,unnamed,unnamedplus

Comment: My vim is probably too old, do you confirm?

Comment: The version should be fine, but the `exclude:...` part must come last, as stated in the help!

Comment: Thank you! The exclude was indeed badly placed. I didn't find unnamed plus and exclude in the clipboard help.. So far, it seems to do what I wanted, so I'll accept!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, here's a solution:

```
vnoremap Y ygv"+y
```

However that does not work, only the other way around:

```
vnoremap Y "+ygvy
```

Here's what it does:

`noremap Y`: Map to the Y key, using default behavior of keybindings. `:h noremap`
`"+y`: Yank into `+` register.
`gv`: Re-select previous visual selection.
`y`: A normal yank into the `*` register (in Linux).

Glad I was able to help you solve it. :)

Comment: @elmanuelito Remember to accept the answer, that way this question actually gets closed. :)

Comment: Hey Eduan, I'm sorry, but after some testing, it's not as expected. I'd really like to have always those two registers equal. Something like mapping "y" to a vim function that does that. with my previous workaround I could do "Yy" or "Yi}". With your solution, it works with selection only. Sorry I didn't see that before. And the must would be to do that with "y" instead of "Y", and to have it work also with mouse selection only...

Comment: @elmanuelito If it only works with selections then it might be worth adding a `v` before the `noremap`, I edited the answer to reflect that. Later when I have access to a computer with Vim I'll try to bake a simple function that does this, in the meanwhile you can use your previous solution. :)

Comment: @elmanuelito I just need a little info. I suppose you would use `y<motion>` correct?

Comment: My main use are: yy ,  yi} and last, make a selection and then press y

Answer (score 1):

Thinking out of the box, you can install [`autocutsel`](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) which sinchronizes both clipboards.

Comment: That seems like a good idea! Although I think if we need to add an extra application it might be a little less useful, know what I mean?

Comment: Hey romainl, I'm not against the idea of an external app, but I tried it without success. On top of vim, I tried with geany. "autocutsel -s PRIMARY" seemed to propagate the Ctrl-C selection to the "Mouse register" and the "Ctrl-V" one. But the opposite didn't work. With vim, something yanked would worked when pasted with the mouse, but not with some ctrl-V (or right click paste) in some other app. I tried "autocutsel" without options, without success as well. I closed the X-apps in between, but not the x-server

Comment: @eduan, `autocutsel`, or rather the syncing feature it provides, can bu useful everywhere. I use a lot of programs besides Vim and having all "pasting" methods paste the same thing sure is useful.

Comment: @romainl Ah I see. Well I think I'll definitelly check it out then. :)

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I've had it running for a long time and I thought that it worked as advertised, which it doesn't. But I had another program running, that does that in a reliable manner: Glippy. Also, `set clipboard^=unnamedplus` is supposed to do what you want but it's not available in every build so YMMV.